# How can I pass username and password in invoke http processor

Tags: apache-nifi

How can I pass username and
Password in invoke http processor. ( I am invoking this  nifi-api/token to generate token ) it’s required username and password to authorise .

I am passing username and password in request username and request password. But still it’s not working

Answer (score 0):

When you want to generate a token for the NiFi API for it to be used in subsequent API calls of NiFi you need to pass the credentials as **x-www-form-urlencoded**.

This can be achieved like this using a cURL command

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://server_URL/nifi-api/access/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'username=<USER_NAME>' \
--data-urlencode 'password=<PASSWORD>'
```

If you are familiar with Postman then you can use the `Body` tab and select `x-www-form-urlencoded` and define the credentials as Key and Value pair. This would generate you the token for the NiFi.